# Are MAC addresses unique over multiple projects in GCE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, virtual-network

I'm pulling instance data from Google Compute Engine from multiple projects. The MAC addresses of the instance interfaces are a unique key in my solution so I need to avoid duplicates. I couldn't find any info on that in the GCE documentation.

I would assume that they are not unique - only unique within the boundaries of one project but I wanted to be sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the current MAC addresses in GCE are not guaranteed to be unique globally. However, these are unique within a GCE network.

This is because the MAC address is calculated based of internal IP no matter whether the internal IP is *user defined* or *auto generated*. As a result, the internal IP does not change throughout the life cycle of the VM; regardless of VM status. Thus, the MAC address might also not be unique within a project boundary.

That being said, if you are searching for unique key then I would suggest using combination of `instance name` and `project number` or `project ID`. This is due to the fact the project number and ID are [unique across Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects).

Comment: Thank you @Taher - seems that I should definitely not rely on the MAC addresses to be unique over project boundaries